# Django, How to access dynamically, related models of object

Tags: python, django

I have the model instance User.

User has two 1 to 1 relations wit another two models,`model1` and `model2`.
I don't want to do `user.model1` instead I want to do something like this:

```
model_name = 'model1'
user.__dict__[model_name]
```

I found that I can do this by:

```
user.__dict__['_wrapped'].__dict__['_' + model_name + '_cache]
```

But I find it ugly, there is another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`getattr(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr) for this:

```
getattr(user, 'model1')
```

`getattr(..)` is a builtin Python functon, and `getattr(x, 'y')` corresponds to `x.y` (note that in the case of `getattr(..)` the second parameter is a string).

In case the object (here `user`) has an attribute `model1`, it will raise an `AttributeError`. `getattr(..)` can however take three parameters as well: a third one is used as a default value, so `getattr(user, 'non_existing_attribute', None)` will return `None` in case the attribute `non_existing_attribute` does not exists.

Comment: thank you, I tried with ```user.get_model()``` but with no success.